# Handle Modal Dialog box input fields using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, automated-tests, puppeteer

I have a webpage , having button to signup.Once i click on signup it shows modal dialog box . I m able to click and get dialogbox, but unable to enter values inside dialog box input fields .Any help with following code

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
puppeteer.launch({headless: false}).then(async browser => {
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.goto('https://paytm.com/paytmwallet');

page.waitForSelector('#site-wrapper > menu-user-screens > div > div > div > div.bigContainer-profile > div > ul > li.last > button');

const login=await page.$('#site-wrapper > menu-user-screens > div > div > div > div.bigContainer-profile > div > ul > li.last > button');
 login.click();

 await page.type('#input_0','87777799')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure the selector is available before trying to type inside just like you did for the site wrapper, therefore all you need do is add the line marked with asterisks to your cade base and you are good to go.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    puppeteer.launch({headless: false}).then(async browser => {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://paytm.com/paytmwallet');

    page.waitForSelector('#site-wrapper > menu-user-screens > div > div > div > div.bigContainer-profile > div > ul > li.last > button');

    const login=await page.$('#site-wrapper > menu-user-screens > div > div > div > div.bigContainer-profile > div > ul > li.last > button');
     login.click();

     **page.waitForSelector('#input_0', {timeout:30000})

     await page.type('#input_0','87777799')
    });
```